# How to create a function that expects an integer value within a range, and decimal values are not accepted, either separated by dot or comma

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I'm trying to create a function that expects a value, as I use it in several parts of the code. I would like to add these protections in case some invalid value is typed (decimal or out of range).

```
unsigned short getChoice(short min, short max) {
    short choice;
    bool valid = false;

    while (!valid) {
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (std::cin.fail() || choice < min || choice > max) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "Invalid Choice, Try Again.\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return choice;
}
```

I got to this code, but it has several problems, as it accepts decimal numbers, rounds down, even if this is not explicit in the code. It's behavior I don't understand.

another problem is that when a number is invalid, when pressing enter, it is pulled by the next std::cin, which naturally shouldn't happen. How do I clear this value?

Comment: So you don't want it to accept decimal points - what should it do if the user enters one?  Should it accept the stuff before and leave the decimal point in the buffer the same way it does with alphabetic characters?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It must ask again for an integer value within the range

Comment: Decimal points work the same way as any other alphabetic character - it leaves it in the stream for the next operator to read.  So `5x` and `5.4` will successfully read the `5` and leave the rest in the buffer.  So to fix that you need to read an entire line using std::getline and then check that it only contains numeric digits.

Comment: this sounds like a job for `std::stringstream`.  You can use `getline()` to get a string from `cin` and then try and parse the correct type from the string.  I'm not sure how `stringstream` fares when given a string that can be converted to the type you want (e.g given a decimal like your example) but you can do what Jerry said and check it against a regex before extracting too.

Comment: @dwcanillas `stringstream` is no different than `cin` in this matter. What is important is HOW the data is parsed, not WHERE it is parsed from. In any case, I wouldn't use `getline` for this function, but at least use a `string` instead of an `int` so `operator>>` can read in the whole decimal. And then parse the `string` into an `int` and retry if that fails. Whether you use `stringstream` or `stoi()` or whatever for that parsing is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

`operator>>` stops reading when it encounters a character that doesn't belong to the type being read in.  So, since you are reading in a `short`, which can't hold a decimal value, if the user types in a decimal value then `operator>>` will happily read in just the integer portion in front of the `.` and leave the rest (including the `'.'`) in the input buffer for subsequent reads.

For example, if the user types in `5.25`, `operator>>` will return `5` and leave `.25` in the input buffer.

For what you are attempting, you need to read in the whole value before you then validate it. I would suggest reading into a `std::string` first, and then parse it afterwards, eg:

```
unsigned short getChoice(short min, short max) {
    std::string input;
    std::size_t pos;
    int value;

    while (std::cin >> input) {
        try {
            value = std::stoi(input, &pos);
            if (input[pos] == '\0' && value >= min && value <= max)
                return static_cast<unsigned short>(value);
        }
        catch (const std::logic_error &) {}

        std::cout << "Invalid Choice, Try Again.\n" << std::endl;
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("input failed");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not Sure what you wanted to tell with the Code you added but if you want to check if a decimal is e.g out of range why dont you just:`

```
int myfunction(int var)
{
if(var>2147483647)
{
cout<<"ERROR! Var out of Range! This may result as an error!";
return 1;
}


//else do something
return 0;

}
```

`
if you e.g give in a float as a Var go give to the function, my debugger gives back an error that this is not Possible. Let me know if this was what you were asking for

Comment: the parameter would just limit the minimum and maximum. The value that cannot be decimal is what the user would put with std::cin for example 1.2